# wp_upload_bits - define (sub)folder / (sub)directory before filename?

Tags: functions, uploads, directory, parameter

I have this code for a plugin I'm using.

```
$comment_image_file = wp_upload_bits( $title . $user->user_login . $comment_id . '.' . $file_ext, null, file_get_contents( $_FILES[ $comment_image_id ]['tmp_name'] ) );
```

So I can grab the postname ($title) and username ($user->user_login) as part of the uploaded filename no problem.

However, I really want these variables to be defined as folders/directories before the filename... rather than as part of the filename string.

In wp_upload_bits it doesn't seem possible. Is there a method that I don't know about... ? Apparently you can use the $time parameter ?

Comment: Have you already tried to fetch something from a custom named location? You might want to inspect that from both ends before investing too much time and energy.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that. I have another plugin for userphotos that saves in it's own dir of /userphoto/ but the method is completely different.